# Date formatter for a certain format of date

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I might missing something, but I can't compose proper date formatter string for the date:

`2016-01-14T10:24:26+0000`

What is 'T' here? and how to include timezone?

My string does not work: `@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss Z"`

Comment: if you want to parse date into any format. you can do like this.NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"dd MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss";
NSString *string = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"Date Current :- %@",string);

Comment: @Jagveer Singh and get nil with this kind of formatter))

Comment: As you've probably guessed 'T' is simply a delimiter character, and for the format documentation you can refer to the standards used at the supported OS versions as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use 'T' in single quotes like below format to retrive string ftom date:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZ
```

Let me know.

Comment: Gosh! F*cking space before 'z' )) Thanks!

Comment: That happens @Stas don't worry! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'";     
NSDate *yourDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:myString];
```